# What is the use of "dran" in the followng sentence. It seems superfluous to me

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure, idiom

A feed

on LinkedIn reads,

> Ich bin ein bisschen spät **dran zum Welttag** der Suizidprävention aber
> bei der Wichtigkeit dieses Themas ...

The emboldening is mine. What is the grammar and meaning of **dran** here? The word seemed superfluous to me. It is colloquial? or is it necessary? I would think ...spät zum Welttag... would be acceptable German. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relant verb phrase is *spät dran sein — to be sort of late*. In contrast *spät sein* just means *to be late*.

The phrase *ein bisschen spät dran sein* is even more excusing. The meaning is something along *to be sort of a little late*.

Comment: Thank you, Janka! I suspected there might be an idiom in there...

Comment: I would have considered *spät sein* as either an anglicism or a poor translation. If *dran* is dropped, I recommend to change the verb e.g. to *kommen*.